# how to capture contents of shopping cart as input in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I capturethe "shoppingCart" selection(s) as an input "formdesc" in the form?

Sample: `<ol id="shoppingCart" name="formdesc"></ol>` does not work.

**HTML:**

```
...
<select id="apparelType">
    <option selected="selected" value="na">Select</option>
    <option value="0">T-Shirt</option>
    <option value="1">Shorts</option>
    <option value="2">Hat</option>
    <option value="3">Bag</option>
</select>

<label for="numb">Total: <span>$</span></label> 
<input id="numb" type="number" name="formbal" value="0.00" /> 
<input id="pretaxTotal" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
<ol id="shoppingCart"></ol>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#apparelType').change(function(){
        var apparelType = $('#apparelType');
        var fmapVal = apparelType.val();

        if (fmapVal == 'na') {
          alert('Please select an apparel type.');
        } else {
          var appVal = [ 15, 20, 25, 30 ];
          var description = apparelType.find('option:selected').text();
          var cost = appVal[fmapVal];

          var pretaxTotal = parseInt($('#pretaxTotal').val());
          var subtotal = pretaxTotal + cost;
          var updatedTotal = ( subtotal * 1.06 ).toFixed(2);

          $('#pretaxTotal').val(subtotal);
          $('#numb').val(updatedTotal);

          $('#shoppingCart').append('<li>' + description + '</li>');
      }
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make another hidden field in the form, and everytime a selection is made, you could add the value (0-3) to the hidden field and add a seperator for each item. So that the field contains something like this `0;3;1;2;3;`. Later you can then split this again in the code where you receive the form data.

In your html it'll look something like this:

```
<input id="techCart" type="hidden" value = ""/>
```

And in your JS you could add:

```
$('#techCart').val($('#techCart').val() + ":" + apparelType.val());
```

At the end of your else part.

See http://jsfiddle.net/5frXU/1/ for a quick test.

Comment: can you provide a sample of hidden field? i have tried and does not work. kinda new to this. thanks

Comment: This works so well (vielen Dank) Chris. One more question: is there a way to pass t-shirt; short instead of 0;2 for example?

Comment: Also, I cannot select tshirt and tshirt again (for quantity of 2)